# How do I mark a field as required when it contains a default value, using bassistance jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Basically all fields in the form are supposed to have a default value if the user doesn't input anything in the field. Is it possible to force the validation plugin to show errors, like required field, while overlooking these default values?

Comment: What's the point of the default value if you want to force the user to enter something?

Comment: The default values serve as labels.

Comment: Then make them labels instead of default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder tag, but it only works in browsers that support html5

```
<input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Enter some keywords..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class eg. clearDefault to your required field and clear it on focus

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clearDefault").focus(function () { $(this).val('');});
    $(".validate").validate();
});

<form class = "validate">
<input type = "text" class = "required clearDefault" name = "foo" value = "Please enter a foo"/>
</form>
```